# useState strange behaviour

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have set 2 arrays with useState in 2 different files:

```
const [filterQuery, setFilterQuery] = React.useState({
        instructor: [],
        material: [],
    })
```

```
const [query, setQuery] = React.useState({
    instructor: [],
    material: [],
  })
```

And i have this function that will update `query` with values from `filterQuery`:

```
const applyFilter = (filterQuery) => {
    setQuery((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      instructor: filterQuery.instructor,
      material: filterQuery.material,
    }));
  }
```

The strange behavior is when i call `setFilterQuery` from a different function, an example is updating `filterQuery` when a button is clicked

```
onClick = (value) => {
   setFilterQuery({
     ...filterQuery,
     instructor: value
   })
}
```

What I expected is it will just update `filterQuery`, but `query` will magically updated with `filterQuery` too whereas it has no connection to the function whatsoever.

What could trigger this ? I have tried a few things, declaring a new variable first before using the `setQuery` :

```
const filter = filterQuery;
setQuery((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      instructor: filter.instructor,
      material: filter.material,
    }));
```

not working.
I have also tried changing the set format without the `prev`, using just `...query` or without them and still not working.

Thank you for reading, helps appreciated.. Will provide more code info / what else I have tried if asked.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem?  It seems pretty likely that there are details missing here.

Comment: @David I have added the other function that called ```setFilterQuery```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript primitive types are passed around as values: meaning that each time a value is assigned, a copy of that value is created.

On the other side objects (including plain objects, array, functions, class instances) are references. If you modify the object, then all variables that reference that object are going to see the change.

Here what basically happens is that you are passing the reference of `query` to `filterQuery`, not the value to `query` that's why when you change either `query` or `filterQuery` they both get updated.
You can see more details and examples at [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) and [difference between values and reference](https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/)

Comment: This seems like the answer I was looking for, will update after I fixed the problem, thank you so much !

Comment: I am happy you got your answer. if it works for you please make sure to mark it as answered.